# AWS Artifact: downloaded reports don't include my company's name

Tags: amazon-web-services, artifact

I need to get SOC2 related report from AWS, and I downloaded it, but found no description of my company/organisation. Instead, the downloaded PDF contains some hexadeimal numbers with hyphens? what is it? Does AWS artifact report involves the user (organization)'s identity? It's not related?

Answer (score 0):

Ah sorry, it was my misunderstanding that AWS is only responsible for its platform, such that the company (and its services) should obtain document separately. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/artifact/latest/ug/what-is-aws-artifact.html
sorry this was stupid question.